# view in JIRA to see work breakdown by developer

Tags: jira

Is there an easy way to get a list in JIRA of work done broken down by developer, by date and by task so you can view individual progress

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For a group, by release, try the Version Workload Report function.

For a specific individual, try the user workload report.

You can get to either of these by clicking "Browse Project" from the dashboard.

Answer (score 0):

Also - the greenhopper plugin provides a lot of this information
(I'm using it almost daily)

Comment: we use greenhopper as well but i want to see a report over time to see how each developer is progressing over time